# NextJS: Loading Font from Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using NextJS along with Tailwind CSS.

In my app, users can select a theme that includes different color schemes along with a pre-selected list of fonts. They can choose a font that they will like for the app.

These are only Google Fonts.

I'm not sure what's the best way to load a font based on the font name received from the database. I can load the data from the `database` in `serverSideProps`, but then how can I load the font before render so that there is no screen flicker. Can you please help?

**UPDATE**

As of now, I've done the following:

1. In `tailwind.config.js`, I've extended the theme with different fonts that are available.

   theme: {
   fontFamily: {
   inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
   cal: ["Cal Sans", "Inter", "sans-serif"],
   arima:['Arima Madurai','cursive'],
   opensans:['Open Sans', 'sans-serif'],
   }
   }
2. I've created a stylesheet for each font, which is stored in public folder at this location:

   /fonts/opensans/stylesheet.css

   /fonts/cal/stylesheet.css

   /fonts/inter/stylesheet.css

   /fonts/arima/stylesheet.css

These stylesheets contain the font. An example below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cal Sans";
  src: url("CalSans-SemiBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("CalSans-SemiBold.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

3. On the page (say `pages/index.js`), I load the user's preferences using `serverSideProps` and pass it to a `Layout` component. This layout component has the `head` which is created through `next/head`. Let's call the font prop received from server as `themeFont`.

Let's say the user's preference is `Cal Sans`, and the user's preference is stored in the database as value `cal`. So, `themeFont` value will be `cal`.

In the head, I load the related stylesheet as follows:

```
<Head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href={`/fonts/${themeFont}/stylesheet.css`}></link>
</Head>
```

4. This will load the `/fonts/cal/stylesheet.css` and the required font. No other font is loaded. Then I can use it in my components with `font-cal` because it has been defined in `tailwind.config.css`

It works fine. I still see a flicker, maybe because of the `font-display:swap`, or maybe it is because of some other reason. But I still feel this is not the optimal solution and this could be done in a better way.

Looking for help in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 1

You are in the right direction, you should use `getServerSideProps` to set the desired font in the `<link>` tag. But you should add `rel="preload"` attribute to load fonts first and then you can place link for your css.

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/fonts/theme-font.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" ></link>
```

The preload value of the  element's rel attribute lets you declare fetch requests in the HTML's , specifying resources that your page will need very soon, which you want to start loading early in the page lifecycle, before browsers' main rendering machinery kicks in.

Then to avoid flicker use `fallback` value for `font-display` property, it will hide the text for about 100ms and, if the font has not yet been downloaded, will use the fallback text.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cal Sans";
  font-display: fallback;
  src: url("CalSans-SemiBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
}
```

You can use the following values for `font-display` for different strategy:

- **auto** (default): Allows the browser to use its default method for loading, which is most often similar to the block value.
- **block**: Instructs the browser to briefly hide the text until the font has fully downloaded. More accurately, the browser draws the text with an invisible placeholder then swaps it with the custom font face as soon as it loads. This is also known as a “flash of invisible text” or FOIT.
- **swap**: Instructs the browser to use the fallback font to display the text until the custom font has fully downloaded. This is also known as a “flash of unstyled text” or FOUT.
- **fallback**: Acts as a compromise between the auto and swap values. The browser will hide the text for about 100ms and, if the font has not yet been downloaded, will use the fallback text. It will swap to the new font after it is downloaded, but only during a short swap period (probably 3 seconds).
- **optional**: Like fallback, this value tells the browser to initially hide the text, then transition to a fallback font until the custom font is available to use. However, this value also allows the browser to determine whether the custom font is even used at all, using the user’s connection speed as a determining factor where slower connections are less likely to receive the custom font.

### Solution 2

As an alternative solution, you can embed your fonts inside your css styles:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cal Sans";
  font-display: fallback;
  src: url(PASTE-BASE64-HERE) format('woff2')
}
```

Check this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-embedded-fonts-dw1v3v?file=/src/App.js) as a reference and there you can convert the woff2 file to base64.

Answer (score 3):

Two ideas:

1. Fontsources maintains a complete repository of Google Fonts as NPM packages. You should be able to dynamically import the font you need as long as its corresponding NPM package is installed.

https://fontsource.org/docs/getting-started

Then you should be able to dynamically import the corresponding font as soon as you know what the font is. I don't know if the font would flicker here.

```js
await import `@fontsource/${fontName}`;
```

This assumes you know `fontName` will be a valid Google Font name, or you'd need a `try`/`catch` for it.

---

2. Another approach is to fetch the font information on the server (if you're using Next.js you could do this with `getServerSideProps`, then use a custom `<Head>` element to point to the corresponding CSS file on `fonts.googleapis.com` and load that as part of the `<Head>` before other content renders (or at least as it's in the process of doing so.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these solutions.

Comment: I tried these options but they cause flicker. I would need some more root-level solution. thanks for your help.

Comment: The second approach (with getServerSideProps) I think should do the job as long as you are fetching the information from the server and loading them in the head of `_app.page.js` . I don't think you can get a `more root-level solution` than getServerSideProps